# Design pattern for modular library in typescript

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

I'm porting a JavaScript project into TypeScript. However, I'm struggling to find a good design pattern for the library to be modular.

### Basic Idea

My library provides a core/minimum functionality. As an example, let's say it returns the browser specs as an object like this:

```
{
    browser:"chrome",
    version:"15.0.3",
    platform:"windows",
    screen-width:"1200",
    // .. etc
}
```

This library will be installed via NPM. But to get the most out of the library, a user has to install "modules" that processes the above object gives a different result.

For example, one module will give what CSS features are not supported in this version of the browser.

```
{
    unsupportedFeatures:[
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        // ... etc
    ]
}
```

Another module will take the core library result AND  the aforementioned module result and process the DOM to see if there's any unsupported CSS defined.

```
{
    notWorking:[
        "a",
        "b",
        // ... etc
    ]
}
```

> Note: This is not the actual function of the library it's just an example to illustrate how modules rely on the core library result and each other's result.

---

### What I have tried

I tried defining the core library as a function then adding modules as prototypes.

One problem with this is that there's no type definition for neither the core library nor the added prototype functions.

- [Example in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Core%20library%20---------------%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20myInterFace%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09browser%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%09version%3Astring%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20function%20CoreLib(this%3A%20myInterFace)%3A%20void%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%0D%0A%09this.browser%20%3D%20%22chrome%22%3B%0D%0A%09this.version%20%3D%20%220.0.1-alpha%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Module%20---------------%0D%0Aexport%20function%20myModule%20(this%3A%20myInterFace)%3Aboolean%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20do%20stuff%0D%0A%09return%20true%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20User%20---------------%0D%0ACoreLib.prototype.myModule%20%3D%20myModule%3B%0D%0Aconst%20instance%20%3D%20new%20CoreLib()%3B%0D%0Ainstance.myModule()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0AProblem%3A%0D%0AAlthough%20there's%20no%20compile%20errors%2C%20but%0D%0Ahover%20over%20instance%2C%20see%20how%20it's%20%22any%22%0D%0Aand%20there's%20no%20auto%20completion%0D%0A*%2F)

I've also tried defining the core library as a class, but that didn't work either, now with compiler errors.

- [Example in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Core%20library%20---------------%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20myInterFace%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09browser%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%09version%3Astring%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20CoreLib%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20browser%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09public%20version%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09constructor()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09%09this.browser%20%3D%20%22chrome%22%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.version%20%3D%20%220.0.1-alpha%22%3B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Module%20---------------%0D%0Aexport%20function%20myModule%20(this%3A%20myInterFace)%3Aboolean%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20do%20stuff%0D%0A%09return%20true%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20User%20---------------%0D%0ACoreLib.prototype.myModule%20%3D%20myModule%3B%0D%0Aconst%20instance%20%3D%20new%20CoreLib()%3B%0D%0Ainstance.myModule()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0AProblem%3A%0D%0AAdding%20prototype%20methods%20causes%20compiler%20error%0D%0A*%2F)

I've also tried merging namespace interface declaration, but it results in other compile errors.

- [Example in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Core%20library%20---------------%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20coreLib%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20moduleInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(myInterface)%3AmyInterFace%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20myInterFace%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20browser%3Astring%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20version%3Astring%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20modules%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20addModule(module%3AmoduleInterface)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20modules.push(module)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20CoreLib%20()%3AmyInterFace%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20result%3A%20myInterFace%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20browser%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20version%3A%22%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20things%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result.browser%20%3D%20%22chrome%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result.version%20%3D%20%220.0.1%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20modules.forEach((module%3AmoduleInterface)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20module(result)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Module%20---------------%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20coreLib%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20myInterface%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20something%3Aboolean%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20myModule%20(input%3AcoreLib.myInterFace)%3AcoreLib.myInterface%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20do%20stuff%0D%0A%09return%20Object.assign(input%2C%7Bsomething%3Atrue%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20User%20---------------%0D%0A%0D%0AcoreLib.addModule(myModule)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20coreLib.CoreLib()%3B%0D%0Aresult.browser%3B%0D%0Aresult.something%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0AProblem%3A%20compile%20errors%0D%0A*%2F)

At this point, I'm out of ideas, All the above solutions are valid JavaScript but doesn't really work in TypeScript.

How can I approach this problem in TypeScript? I think it's fairly common to write librares that are modular/extensible in this way, so what it the ideal design pattern to follow? Given that it provides type saftey and auto-completion for the core library, the module author and the user.

Comment: Have you looked at [RxJS 5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS#installation-and-usage) to see how it is structured? It is modular and has modular TypeScript declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your playground code to look like something I might have used:

```
// Core library ---------------
namespace coreLib { 
    export interface myInterface { 
        browser:string,
        version: string
    }

    const modules: ((myInterface) => coreLib.myInterface)[] = [];
    export function addModule(module: (myInterface) => coreLib.myInterface) { 
        modules.push(module);
    }

    export function CoreLib ():myInterface { 
        let result: myInterface = {
            browser: "",
            version: ""
        }
        // do things
        result.browser = "chrome";
        result.version = "0.0.1";
        modules.forEach((module) => { 
            result = module(result);
        })
        return result;
    }
}

// Module ---------------
namespace coreLib {
    export interface myInterface {
        something?: boolean;
    }
    export function myModule (input:coreLib.myInterface): coreLib.myInterface { 
        // do stuff
        input.something = true;
        return input;
    } 
}

// User ---------------
coreLib.addModule(coreLib.myModule);
const result = coreLib.CoreLib();
console.log(result.browser);
console.log(result.something);
```